# Error messages on Android emulator bootup in Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-2.2

I am using Android Studio 2.2 on a Windows 10 x64 platform. My virtual device is a Nexus 5 with API 22. When I boot up this virtual device in the emulator I get these messages on bootup. I also get the same errors with API's 23 and 24. Can someone help me with that these messages are and how to resolve these errors? Specifically "goldfish_audio_in" and ColorBuffer and glDrawElements() errors. I cannot debug any application because they keep crashing.

```
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cdd
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cdd
draw: Could not glDrawElements() error=0x506
draw: Could not glDrawElements() error=0x506
draw: Could not glDrawElements() error=0x506
draw: Could not glDrawElements() error=0x506
```